# Can I use SLComposeViewController in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've written some code for my app, with that code a created two buttons, one for sharing with Twitter and one for sharing with Facebook.
My app deployment target is iOS 5.1+.
I made the Twitter and Facebook share sheets with SLComposeViewController.

My question is very simple: Is it possible to use SLComposeViewController in iOS 5.1?

Comment: Have you tested it in the 5.1 simulator? Does it crash?

Comment: Please look at the reference docs for the class in question before posting such a question. The docs tell you when the class was added. You can't use it in a version of iOS prior to that.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. You can't.

You need iOS 6 (or 6+) devices or simulators for testing this, Else the app will crash on iOS 5 and earlier versions.

**Note:**

In iOS 5 you can use `TWTweetComposeViewController` for displaying the twitter composer but there is no option for facebook in iOS 5.